# TSHARK Exclude Filter

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I'm having trouble **excluding** the **dns.a** fields within this command.. Anyone have any ideas?

I simply want it to show dns queries, but not ones that point to 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1

> sudo tshark -i enp2s0 -f "src port 53" -Y "(ip.dst!=192.168.1.50)&&(dns.a!=0.0.0.0)&&(dns.a!=127.0.0.1)" -n -T fields -e ip.dst -e dns.qry.name

Comment: Please provide a sample of both expected and actual results. The command provided should have output provided matching dns traffic.

Comment: I simply want it to show dns queries, but not ones that point to 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1.. 192.168.1.50 is my dns server. So i ignored that as well.

Comment: In my testing, a modified form of this command works as described. You can test in a separate terminal with `nslookup <domain name> <DNS server>` while running this command. If you're still having problems, provide a link to the relevant capture (using google drive, dropbox, etc.).

Comment: For me it still shows dns queries, regardless that they're 0.0.0.0 or not. The only filter excluded that works is the ip.dst!

Comment: Can you write the traffic to a packet capture (`-w <file>`) and provide a link to it here?